# Intercepting differents XHR requests with same url in Playwright Python

Tags: python, request, xmlhttprequest, playwright

I'm using Playwright to intercepting XHR requests and save directly data I need.
The XHR requests that i'm intercepting is encoded as json files.

Here the terminal of Network in the navigator :
[image: Network terminal in navigator]
The XHR request that i'm intercepting is the file 'get_movie_sessions_cine.php'.

Here the code in my project to intercepting the content of the file :

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright 
import json 
def scrapping_XHR(url, name_php_file):
    data = []
    with sync_playwright() as p: 
        def handle_response(response): 
            # the endpoint we are insterested in 
            if (name_php_file in response.url): 
                data.append(json.dumps(response.json()))
        browser = p.chromium.launch() 
        page = browser.new_page() 
        page.on("response", handle_response) 
        page.goto(url, wait_until="networkidle") 
        page.context.close() 
        browser.close()
    return json.loads(data[-1])
```

And to use the function I just need to run it like that :

```py
link_film_sheet = 'https://www.ticketingcine.fr/index.php?lang=fr&idMS=FRMVR9H&nc=1242'
json_fiche_film = scrapping_XHR(link_film_sheet, 'get_movie_sessions_cine')
```

But when I click on the button 'Choisir une date' to change the date and select an other date, it generate me an other 'get_movie_sessions_cine.php' file in the terminal of network :
[image]
The content of these files is different but I can't intercepting just the last one added to the network with my code.
I have just access to the first one 'get_movie_sessions_cine.php' file, so it is not the last updated file.

How can I do to fix this issue ?